# Open source note-taking app with tagging

Tags: windows, linux, open-source, note-taking

I need a desktop application for organizing notes (or outliner, journal …) with powerful tagging feature. 
I will use it for writing a lot of ideas and conclusions, so I need tags for quickly filtering very large number of texts. Tree structure is ok, but it is not enough for this purpose.

I tried about 20 different apps but I still can't find one that have all of this features:

- powerful tag support (multiple tags can be assigned to one note, and later easy filtering notes using existing tags)
- **offline** storing notes in (SQLite) database
- strong encryption support
- working on Linux and Windows
- open source
- rich text formating (it's ok to have just basic options for this)

I found a lot of good applications but often they haven't tag feature or it is useless.
Good examples are [Personal Historian](http://www.rootsmagic.com/personal-historian/) and [CintaNotes](http://cintanotes.com/) (have very nice tagging and save data in SQL Lite), but they are not open source or there is no Linux version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option I know of is [zim wiki](http://zim-wiki.org/). It doesn't have encryption support but you could store notebooks in an encrypted volume with veracrypt or similar. The rest of the features you want it meets.

Comment: It doesn't store data in single database file (which can be useful for data migration later), but it's probably the closest solution in this situation. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I was pretty sure I had seen the ability to save in or export to a database. Can't find it now, sorry. I agree it's still your best option though. Everything being text files makes it simple to do whatever you want with them.